# Did the Stuxnet virus attack the International Space Station?

Tags: computers, space-flight, virus

Over at [Extreme Tech](http://www.extremetech.com/extreme/170785-the-american-made-stuxnet-virus-has-infected-the-international-space-station)

> Last year, news broke that a virus sabotaged the Iranian uranium enrichment program. It seemed all too convenient at the time — and as it turned out, the virus, Stuxnet, was actually engineered by the United States and Israel. Now, the man-made virus has ventured into space, and made its way to the International Space Station.

Is this true?

Comment: Stuxnet should: a) not have impact on anything other than the Iranian uranium enrichment plant and b) not be able to get into computers anymore at this point, unless they have been ignoring security updates for a long, long time.

Comment: @fNek The point isn't whether it did damage, but whether it could get in at all. Would you be okay if someone broke into your house but didn't steal anything because you weren't Iranian? About B, the claim is that it happened two years ago.